# Google Iframes issue

Tags: javascript

After hosting google frames html page. I'm getting an error like this:

> cb=gapi.loaded_0:154 GET
>   [https://play.google.com/work/apps?usegapi=1&usegapi=1&origin=https://192.168.0.223&gsrc=3p&jsh=m;/*/scs/apps-static/*/js/k%3Doz.gapi.en.tZDXb_qbHrc.O/m%3D__features__/am%3DAQ/rt%3Dj/d%3D1/rs%3DAGLTcCOgQjGru3ruZo70XwAerRmnfOfOeA&etok=WAFX9RHuN55VaiZM_AlanMAxabxxu_V-Vzq7m3MqLK5mLxxvqsRgx_y177_7U6-3bkpjufdZVThjtMQcn-PCI1cJLkS9VwQlHYY7YNETKncL2Z0ykKzA0ifnhd8eLy7vnoVfJt-eTB90k](https://play.google.com/work/apps?usegapi=1&usegapi=1&origin=https://192.168.0.223&gsrc=3p&jsh=m;/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k%3Doz.gapi.en.tZDXb_qbHrc.O/m%3D__features__/am%3DAQ/rt%3Dj/d%3D1/rs%3DAGLTcCOgQjGru3ruZo70XwAerRmnfOfOeA&etok=WAFX9RHuN55VaiZM_AlanMAxabxxu_V-Vzq7m3MqLK5mLxxvqsRgx_y177_7U6-3bkpjufdZVThjtMQcn-PCI1cJLkS9VwQlHYY7YNETKncL2Z0ykKzA0ifnhd8eLy7vnoVfJt-eTB90k)
>   500 ();[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUNCX.jpg)

Comment: The error message says you got a 500 Internal Server Error. If I click the link, it shows an internal server error. Why would you expect a different result for that URL under any other condition?

Comment: actually i m trying to create play store in my website using google api before 7 to 8 days ago it will work fine. but now it will shows error like this 500 error. u have any idea how can i make google play store in my website.

Answer (score -1):

If you press F12 in your browser and go to console. You will see this error. [image]

It says No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' when it is trying to go to stathat.com...It could be a CORS issue. Here is a video about it: https://www.codeschool.com/discuss/t/how-to-solve-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-origin-null-is-therefore-not-allowed-access-in-angular-js/28989/2

Comment: after accessing html page and after inspect that page i will get likethis.